# How to make function in ORACLE which will calculate values in column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
 ID_ROLE      NAME_OF_ROLE    
----------   -------------   
  1           Manager        
  2           Director        
  4           Supervisor          
  8           Secretary
  16          Controlor
  ...
  2048        Boss
```

This is my ORACLE table. As you can see, column ID_ROLE is power of number 2. First role is 2 to the power of 0, second role is 2 to the power of 1, last role is 2 to the power of 11, etc. This is easy when somebody has only one role, I can make CASE or DECODE function. For example, if ID_ROLE is 2 than the person is "Director". But the problem is when somebody have two or more roles. If ID_ROLE is 24 (for example) it means that the person has role "Secretary" and  "Controlor" (8 + 16) and it should return text like this "Secretary / Controlor".

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Oracle is a relational database. Why not create a table where a person has more than 1 relation to a role?

Comment: This question will provide the answer for getting the nth bit value of a number.
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51124/get-a-number-nth-bit-value-in-oracle

Comment: I'll second Rene's comment -- this is not how relational databases should be designed. If you added an intersection table between user and role you could also add attributes to describe that relationship, such as the period of validity.

Comment: While I do understand and might even agree with @Rene's and David Aldridge's objections, I think it's an interesting approach and does eliminate the need for a join table.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm not sure that I'd be willing to swap a join table for a join that involves a bitand operation, tbh.

Comment: @DavidAldridge As I said, I understand those concerns, and would probably not model it like this myself either. From a performance standpoint, however, I don't think the `BITAND` will be significantly slower (if at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using

- [`BITAND`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions021.htm#SQLRF00612) to perform the bitwise AND operation; and
- [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) to join the role names separated by a slash (available from 11g onwards)

```
SELECT LISTAGG(NAME_OF_ROLE, ' / ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID_ROLE) "ROLE_NAMES"
FROM ROLES
WHERE BITAND(ID_ROLE, 24) = ID_ROLE;
```

Which results in an output of:

```
+------------------------+
| ROLE_NAMES             |
+------------------------+
| Secretary / Controller |
+------------------------+
```

The DDL I used:

```
CREATE TABLE  "ROLES" (
    "ID_ROLE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME_OF_ROLE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     CONSTRAINT "ROLES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_ROLE") USING INDEX ENABLE
);
```

And my test data:

```
INSERT INTO ROLES (NAME_OF_ROLE, ID_ROLE) VALUES ('Manager', 1);
INSERT INTO ROLES (NAME_OF_ROLE, ID_ROLE) VALUES ('Director', 2);
INSERT INTO ROLES (NAME_OF_ROLE, ID_ROLE) VALUES ('Supervisor', 4);
INSERT INTO ROLES (NAME_OF_ROLE, ID_ROLE) VALUES ('Secretary', 8);
INSERT INTO ROLES (NAME_OF_ROLE, ID_ROLE) VALUES ('Controller', 16);
INSERT INTO ROLES (NAME_OF_ROLE, ID_ROLE) VALUES ('Boss', 2048);
```